# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app' when add plugin idea

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

intelliJ IDEA 2022.2 (Community Edition)

java 8

In build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id "com.nocwriter.runsql" version "1.0.3"
    id 'idea'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
}
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

group = 'com.myproject'
version = '2.0.6'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

idea {
    project {
        languageLevel = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
}
```

But I get error in this line:

```
project {


Error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/myproject/app/build.gradle' line: 31

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Value is null
```

Comment: Do you mean that it works fine if you comment "id 'idea'" line?

Comment: @y.bedrov It's works if I remove section "idea {...}"

Comment: Why did you add this part there?

Comment: @y.bedrov Can you ask me correct place for idea {}?

Comment: Please describe why do you need that part? Seems it should work without it.

Comment: @y.bedrov With this section the IntellIJ IDEA is better work with Gradle

Comment: Similar issue is discussed here: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/issues/58. Seems new issue should be reported against "gradle-idea-ext-plugin"